# React nested components with checkboxes

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a website that contains more than a dozen components.
 Each parent component contains about 5 other components. Each 5 components contains a form. 
 Parent components has 3 checkboxes. 
1: Expand all components in that offer (expand all), 
2: assign everything in that component (assign all), 
3: Expand the component (expand product).
 Each child component has two checkboxes.
1: Expand the component (also expand product),
 2: assign everything from the component (also assign all). 
All of these options works on a state change. They all work correctly. The problem is that when I click parent checkbox, I can not deselect the child's single component. So I can not uncheck the checkbox inside child's component (child's expand product or child's assign all)

[closed components](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ba8ZS.jpg)
[expand product on parent](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PzACz.jpg)
[expand product in parent, expand product in child](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zMmx1.jpg)
[expand all in parent,triggers expand product in parent and it triggers expand product in childs component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8lpz3.jpg)

here's first file that renders parent component :

```
 class Offer extends React.Component {
 constructor(props){
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        checkedItems: new Map()
    };

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
}

handleChange(e) {
    const item = e.target.name;
    const isChecked = e.target.checked;

    this.setState(prevState => ({
        checkedItems: prevState.checkedItems.set(item, isChecked)
    }));
}

render(){
    const { data, country_offer, country_offer_tab, countries, } = this.props;

    return (
        <div className="offer-wrapper">
            <div className={"offer-header " + data[2] }>
                <div>
                    <div className="custom_checkbox">
                        <div className="custom_checkbox">
                            <input
                                type={"checkbox"}
                                name={`${data[2]}_expand_all`}
                                className="expand_all"
                                checked={this.state.checkedItems.get(`${data[2]}_expand_all`) || false}
                                onChange={this.handleChange}
                                id={`${data[2]}_expand_all`}
                            />
                            <label htmlFor={`${data[2]}_expand_all`}>Expand all</label>
                        </div>
                        <div className="custom_checkbox">
                            <input
                                type={"checkbox"}
                                name={`${data[2]}_assign_all`}
                                className="assign_all"
                                checked={this.state.checkedItems.get(`${data[2]}_assign_all`) || false}
                                onChange={this.handleChange}
                                id={`${data[2]}_assign_all`}
                            />
                            <label htmlFor={`${data[2]}_assign_all`}>Assign all products</label>
                        </div>
                        <div className="custom_checkbox">
                            <input
                                type={"checkbox"}
                                name={`${data[2]}_expand_product`}
                                className="expand_product"
                                checked={( this.state.checkedItems.get(`${data[2]}_expand_product`) || this.state.checkedItems.get(`${data[2]}_expand_all`) ) || false}
                                onChange={this.handleChange}
                                id={`${data[2]}_expand_product`}
                            />
                            <label htmlFor={`${data[2]}_expand_product`}>Expand product</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            {
                (this.state.checkedItems.get(`${data[2]}_expand_all`) || this.state.checkedItems.get(`${data[2]}`+'_expand_product'))  &&
                    <CountryOffer
                        country_offer_tab={country_offer_tab}
                        countries={countries}
                        data={data}
                        expand_all={this.state.checkedItems.get(`${data[2]}_expand_all`)}
                        expand_product={this.state.checkedItems.get(`${data[2]}_expand_product`)}
                        assign_all={this.state.checkedItems.get(`${data[2]}_assign_all`)}
                    />
            }
        </div>
    )
}
}

export default Offer;
```

and here is child component

```
class CountryOffer extends React.Component{
constructor(props){
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        checkedItems: new Map(),
    };

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
}

handleChange(e) {
    if (!this.props.expand_all){
        const item = e.target.name;
        const isChecked = e.target.checked;

        this.setState(prevState => ({
            checkedItems: prevState.checkedItems.set(item, isChecked)
        }));
    } else {
        console.log('cant uncheck/check this')
    }
}

render(){
    const { country_offer_tab, countries, data, expand_all, expand_product, assign_all} = this.props;
    return (
        <div className={"offer-details " + data[2]}>
            {country_offer_tab[data[2]].map((country, k) => {
                return (
                    <div key={k}>
                        <div className="offer-country-header" >
                            <div>
                                <span className={"iti-flag "+(countries[k].symbol).toLowerCase()}/>
                                <span>{countries[k].name}</span>
                            </div>
                            <div className='custom_checkbox'>
                                <input
                                    checked={assign_all ? assign_all : (this.state.checkedItems.get(`intersections_for ${data[2]}|${countries[k].id}`) || false)} onChange={this.handleChange}
                                    type="checkbox"
                                    name={"intersections_for "+ data[2] + '|' + countries[k].id}
                                    id={"intersections_for "+ data[2] + '|' + countries[k].id}/>
                                <label className="intersections_group_label" htmlFor={"intersections_for "+ data[2] + '|' + countries[k].id}>Check/uncheck all</label>
                            </div>
                            <div className='custom_checkbox'>
                                <input
                                    checked={expand_all ? expand_all : (this.state.checkedItems.get(`expand_geo ${data[2]}|${countries[k].id}`) || false)} onChange={this.handleChange}
                                    type="checkbox"
                                    name={"expand_geo " + data[2] + '|' + countries[k].id}
                                    id={"expand_geo " + data[2] + '|' + countries[k].id}/>
                                <label htmlFor={"expand_geo "+ data[2] + '|' + countries[k].id}>Expand GEO</label>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        {
                            (expand_all || this.state.checkedItems.get(`expand_geo ${data[2]}|${countries[k].id}`)) &&
                                <CountryOfferIntersections
                                    country_offer_tab={country_offer_tab}
                                    offer_id={data[2]}
                                    country_id={countries[k].id}
                                    check_all={this.state.checkedItems.get(`intersections_for ${data[2]}|${countries[k].id}`)}
                                    assign_all={assign_all}
                                    expand_product={expand_product}
                                />
                        }
                    </div>
                )
            })}
        </div>
    )}
}

 export default CountryOffer;
```

I will be grateful for any help

Comment: In cases where two or more components both "own" the same state, I would recommend using some flavor of flux (for example redux). Have you considered that? Or you should make the child component stateless and have the parent own all state. Pass down event listeners and state as props to the children.

https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html

Comment: I'm not using redux right now. You think It's necessary here? If it is, i will consider it. Btw, do you understand my issue correctly? I can't uncheck/check checkbox when `expand all`->`expand product`( in parent)-> `expand product`(in child component) because of state.

Comment: It's possible to do everything without redux. But the more complicated an app gets, the more useful it is to have a consistent way to manage state.

Comment: I can't quite understand your code. Is the child component the same as the parent component (did you mean to include the code for `CountryOfferIntersections`? In any case, when you post a question seeking help debugging, only include relevant code. Simplify the example. 90% of the lines of code you included are probably not relevant to your question. [mcve]

Comment: @HåkenLid oh, sorry. I fixed it, can you take a look now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `true`, the `assign_all` prop overrides any local state in `CountryOffer`

```
checked={assign_all ? assign_all : ...
```

This is a problem with not having a single source of truth. I would refactor your code so that `CountryOffer` is a stateless component, and keep all state in the parent `Offer` component.

Alternatively lifting management of shared state out of the components altogether. (For example with [react context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html), redux,  rxjs)

Comment: I get it. But take a look at my last screenshot. My child component has a form inside and it renders, when child component has active expand product. Parent->child->child tree. how to menage one source of truth here?

Comment: Sometimes complex problems require complex solutions. This is why people use things like redux. Since you want to be able to change `expand` both from the parent and from the child, `expanded` should not be local state in the child. Both ux state (expanded) and form data (checked) can be lifted up together. This is a major refactoring of your code, so I can't provide a full solution.

Comment: thank you so much for your help. 
I appreciate it a lot.